# How to modify values that are result of fnGetNodes() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to get all of the values on a 4th column of my datatable table. (both visible and unvisible rows).The 4th column of each row is consist of a checkbox. After I get them, I need to change 'checked' property of them and send back to table. Currently, I'm able to get data but I do not know how could I send them back to datatable after modifying. In the column that I'm trying to retrieve checkboxes are exist.  Here is my code :

```
$(document).on('click', '#select_all', function()
{

    var rows = $("#results_container table").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
    var cells = [];
    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
   {
       // Get HTML of 4rd column (for example)
      console.log( $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(3)"));
   }


});
```

Here is what console.log statement prints out :

```
[td.sorting_1, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: tr, selector: "td:eq(3)"]
```

The check property that I want to modify is under 0: td.sorting_1 -> childNodes  [screen shoot of my console view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7s0keabzhsmeenz/Screenshot%202015-09-04%2013.24.02.png?dl=0)

So how could I changed this checked value and see the result on my datatable?

Comment: could you give your html file?

Comment: @guvenckardas I create datatable dynamically, so I dont have anything in my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop store your data to a variable:

```
var dataHolder = $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(3)")
```

Then access your data like this:

```
dataHolder = dataHolder[0].childNodes;
```

Then try your console.log() on the dataHolder.
You should be able to change the value like this:

```
dataHolder[1].checked = true;
```